# React: Cannot get state slice to update, but other state properties work fine

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, state

Using these two pieces of state:

```
this.markerArray = [];
this.arrayLength = 0;
```

I am trying to use this function:

```js
getMarkers = () => {
  this.dbRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((marker) => {
      if (!this.markerArray.includes(marker.id)) {
        let currentID = marker.id;
        let appObj = {
          ...marker.data(),
          ["id"]: currentID,
        };
        this.markerArray.push(appObj);
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      markerArray: this.markerArray,
    });
    // (problem code) this.setState({arrayLength: this.markerArray.length})

    return this.markerArray;
  });
};
```

To update a list of map markers. I am trying to update this.arrayLength when this.markerArray's length changes. I think the problem has to do with setState's asynchronous nature, but I can't figure out what to do with that information.

I have tried:

1. Creating a separate function to set arrayLength
2. Passing that function as a callback when setting markerArray's state
3. Calling the function in Render (infinite loop)
4. Setting arrayLength in the same setState as markerArray
5. Changing the initial value of arrayLength to null, 0, and ''

I have even tried setting arrayLength to an arbitrary number that does not rely on markerArray.length, but it won't update.

Comment: Any reason you can't just get rid of `this.arrayLength` all together and just use `this.marketArray.length` directly?

Comment: I was trying to make a comparison so that I could use a conditional later to run getMarkers() once, without it causing an infinite loop. The conditional is like (if this.arrayLength !== this.marketArray.length) { getMarkers() (or setState.(arrayLength: this.marketArray.length}. I understand that there are problems calling setState in render(), but I was trying to work around them.

Comment: I got you. Well I'm not sure I have the answer off the top of my head, but was just throwing it out there in case the answer was that simple. One thing I do see: your `getMarkers` function seems to be async (`.get().then()...`), but it's not marked as sync. Try `getMarkers = async () => {...}` for starters.

Comment: I tried a couple different async setups. Honestly I think it's because of how I set up the arrayLength prop, but I don't know what is wrong with it. It won't update under any circumstances